# In my angular service, how do I initialize a variable one-time from a $resource

Tags: angularjs

What I want to do is once-only load an object from a resource which will be the constant template for various calls served by my service later on. I'm thinking my service factory function would look something like this:

```
function assetService($resource, DataConstants){
    var assetTemplate = $resource(DataConstants.PATH_GET_ASSET).get({});
    return {
        createAsset: createAsset
    };

    function createAsset(subscription){
        var Asset = $resource("/assets");
        var newAsset = new Asset(assetTemplate);
        newAsset.serialNo = subscription.serialNumber;
        return newAsset.$save().$promise;
    }
}
```

I'm thinking that my code has issues... what if my $resource code for initializing assetTemplate fails? Can I get some advice on the best way to one-time initialize a variable used over and over again in my service?

Comment: `$resource` is an API abstraction layer. Since your data is constant and all you need is to persist it use `$localStorage`,  `$sessionStorage` or `$cookies`.

Comment: I would prefer to have the assetTemplate only available within the assetService. I think $localStorage and $sessionSorage and $cookies have my value much more universally available.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use a service or localStorage. This way the variable can persist. You would need to inject the service everywhere that you need access to the data.

Comment: localStorage sounds like more than I need. I do not need the variable available outside of my assetService. Probably all I am trying to achieve is to obtain the value of the template once only at application startup. Is creating another service for this implementation detail my only option?

Comment: LocalStorage will remain intact on page refresh. if you are persisting constant data then a service will be fine.